# Add ToolbarItem in Xamarin.Forms with F#

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms, toolbar

My Xamarin.Forms project contains PCL in F#. I want to add ToolbarItem on the page which navigate to some other page. How should it be done?

With my code, error comes that "The value or constructor 'this' is not defined".

This is my code:

```
type SomePage() = 
    inherit ContentPage()

    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<SomePage>)

    let toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem("O", "icon", (fun() -> this.Navigation.PushAsync(OtherPage())), ToolbarItemOrder.Default, 0)
    do base.ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem)
```

Comment: `type SomePage() as this` ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, I am able to use SomePage() as this but it is doing nothing, I mean not navigating to other page.